# C# Progressbar filling while method is working

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Im building a little app which has a long loading time.

I want to display this loading time in a progressbar to see how long i have to wait till the programm is loaded.

I hope you understand what i want..

I tried the backgroundworker already but dont understand how to use it, in every example they use in the DoWork Event a simple

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
//method etc here
backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i);
}
```

But in my eyes this is senseless for me because this only repeats my method...

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Aktie dataAktie = new Aktie(aktien_name);

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {

                    dataAktie.ReadFromDatabase();
                    dataAktie.FetchData();             
                    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i);
              }
            }


        private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
//Controls that have to be filled
}
```

But this Controls dont get data im veryyyyy confused

Comment: Add a progress changed event - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I use this already, i mean its dont working without this event but it only reports the progress to the progressbar but this wasn't my question.

Comment: " because this only repeats my method...": no, the entire for-loop **is** your method. In your method you have to call ReportProgress, because that's the only way to actually estimate it.

Comment: You need to call ReportProgress from the code in your app which is causing the 'long loading time'. If it's pulling data from the database, or initialising other stuff, you need a way of passing the progress over to the progressbar. If you don't have any control over the code which is causing the delay, you can have a progressbar with its style set to 'Marquee'.

Comment: I dont know if i dont understand your answer or if you dont understand my question but this is the code i already have in dowork

Comment: @Coder64 I'm afraid you don't understand the usage of ReportProgress. The for-loop from 1 to 100 is just an *sample* method that simulates some work.

Comment: Yeah! Thats what i thinking about too ! But how do i report the progress? Thats my question!

Answer (score 1):

The following code example demonstrates the use of the ReportProgress method to report the progress of an asynchronous operation to the user.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // This method will run on a thread other than the UI thread. 
    // Be sure not to manipulate any Windows Forms controls created 
    // on the UI thread from this method.
    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, "Working...");
    Decimal lastlast = 0;
    Decimal last = 1;
    Decimal current;
    if (requestedCount >= 1)
    { AppendNumber(0); }
    if (requestedCount >= 2)
    { AppendNumber(1); }
    for (int i = 2; i < requestedCount; ++i)
    {
        // Calculate the number. 
        checked { current = lastlast + last; }
        // Introduce some delay to simulate a more complicated calculation.
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        AppendNumber(current);
        backgroundWorker.ReportProgress((100 * i) / requestedCount, "Working...");
        // Get ready for the next iteration.
        lastlast = last;
        last = current;
    }


    backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(100, "Complete!");
}
```

** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A `BackgroundWorker` and it's `ReportProgress` method are no magic wanda that simply shows you any progress you want, you actually have to change your code to do so.

The `DoWork` event handler should contain the code you want to execute in the background. Ideally this is something for progress can be measured easily. For example if you have to process 10 items then after each item you could say I'm now 10% further done. That's why the example code contains a for loop.

Your code only contains two method calls, `ReadFromDatabase` and `FetchData`. So you *could* simply do

```
dataAktie.ReadFromDatabase();
backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(50); // 50% done
dataAktie.FetchData(); 
backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(100); // 100% done
```

Obviously that not really perfect. The only way to have more accurate progress is to change the `ReadFromDatabase` and `FetchData` methods, for example let them take the `BackgroundWorker` object as a parameter so that they can also report progress, or provide a callback for that.

Comment: Thank you! Thats what i wanted to know! And its really not perfect like you said, but how i take backgroundworker as parameter?

Comment: @Coder64 For example you have to change `void ReadFromDatabase()` into `void ReadFromDatabase(BackgroundWorker worker)`, then you can call `worker.ReportProgress` inside that method. But that would be a breaking change and probably not the best solution. And it only matters if you can predict the progress more accurately inside that method.